# Data is not inserted in one table (father_new) but appears in another table (lab5_students)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert data into two different tables.
One is (father_new) and another is (lab5_students) but the data is inserted in lab5_student's table and does not show in father_new.
I have used stored procedure and i'm not sure where have i done wrong.

This is my code to save Father's record

```
private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbox_Fname1.Text) == true || String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbox_fdob.Text) == true || String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbox_fcnic.Text) == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Name,DOB,Cnic fields are compulsary to fill");
    }

    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Lab5task2", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Action", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = btn_Psubmit.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_Fname1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FNum", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = tbox_fnum.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FOccup", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_occupation.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_femail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FDOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(tbox_fdob.Text, "d-M-yyyy", null);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Foffic_Num", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = tbox_offnum.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FAge", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = tbox_fage.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FState", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_Fstate.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FIncome", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = tbox_fincome.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FCnic", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = tbox_fcnic.Text;
                                conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

    }
}
```

this is to save student's record

```
private void btn_Ssubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbox_sname.Text) == true || String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbox_sfname.Text) == true || String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbox_sid.Text) == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Name,Father's Name and Id fields are compulsary to fill");
    }
    else
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Lab5task2", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Action", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = btn_Ssubmit.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_sname.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sid", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = tbox_sid.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sfather_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_sfname.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sphone", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_sphone.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Semail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_semail.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Saddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_saddress.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sage", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_sage.Text;

        if (rbtn_female.Text == "Female")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sgender", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = rbtn_female.Text;
        }
        else if (rbtn_male.Text == "Male")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sgender", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = rbtn_male.Text;
        }

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ssemester", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =      tbox_ssemester.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Suniversity", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbox_suni.Text;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

this my my stored procedure

```
create procedure [dbo].[lab5task2]
(
      -- For Parent data
      @FName nvarchar(50)=null,
      @FNum nchar(50) =null,
      @FOccup nvarchar(50)=null,
      @FEmail nvarchar(50)=null,
      @FDOB datetime=null,
      @Foffic_Num nchar(50)=null,
      @FAge nchar(50)=null,
      @FState nvarchar(50)=null,
      @FIncome nchar(50)=null,
      @FCnic nchar(50)=null,
      -- For Student data
      @Sname nvarchar(50)=null,
      @Sid nchar(50)=null,
      @Sfather_name nvarchar(50)=null,
      @Sphone nvarchar(50)=null,
      @Semail nvarchar(50)=null,
      @Saddress nvarchar(50)=null,
      @Sage nvarchar(50)=null,
      @Sgender nvarchar(50)=null,
      @Ssemester nchar(50)=null,
      @Suniversity nvarchar(50)=null,
      @Action nvarchar(50)=null
)
```

[continued procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sceam.png)

Comment: What is exactly the text of the button _btn_Psubmit_ (upper and lower case included because the make a difference inside the SP code)

Comment: Steve the text was exactly the same in the procedure as'Save Data' for father's table. The problem was in 'Delete All' . I failed to notice  that if statement thanks to @mjwills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this part of your stored proc.

```
if @Action = 'Delete All'
delete from lab5_students;
delete from father_new;
```

It does not do what you think it does. I **suspect** you think that the `if` applies to **both** the delete lines. But it only applies to the first. You are effectively doing:

```
if @Action = 'Delete All'
    delete from lab5_students;

delete from father_new; // i.e. always run this
```

As such, you need to use [`BEGIN ... END`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189079%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
if @Action = 'Delete All'
BEGIN
    delete from lab5_students;
    delete from father_new;
END
```

This will ensure that the second `DELETE` executes **only** if `@Action` is 'Delete All'.

Comment: yes mjwills it helped :D code is running perfectly thanks a lot dude. God bless you